# Would a world-sheet through phase-space make sense?

Tags: phase-space

Imagine every possible configuration of the Universe as points in a phase-space.

A path from one point A to another point B represents a 'history'.

This is a one dimensional idea.

But imagine instead of a 1D path, one constructs a 2D world-sheet through this phase space.

I wonder if this would make any kind of physical sense. Each state of the Universe would have to be represented by a loop in phase-space rather than a point. A kind of loopy-phase-space.

This would probably not be of much use?
I imagine it would be similar to phase-space but with an extra dimension. i.e. each point in phase space would represent a $D-1$ slice of the universe.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether it is in configuration space or phase space, the 1-dimensionality of the world line is because time is 1-dimensional. As a path, the world line is essentially parameterised by what can be called the proper time of the object whose world line it is. So, a 2-dimensional world sheet implies 2 dimensions of time. This type of theory certainly is studied - simply use a metric with a signature with more than one entry of each sign. However, AFAIK, no useful theory of our own cosmos has come from this approach so far.

**Note:** if you meant that the world sheet is the union of the world lines of multiple particles within the theory, then that is a different matter. And this is moving toward such things as the idea of flux within phase space. The meaning of which seems clear to me - as a mathematical construct.

Comment: This is incorrect - string theory is a 2-parameter theory, albeit usually framed in configuration space, and it is by no means true that both parameters have an interpretation as "time"

Comment: I feel that is covered by my addendum.

Comment: A string is *not* considered to be a union of individual point particles, even in the tensionless limit where this might have made sense.

Comment: Well if it was a tube, it would imply the extra time dimension was compact. Perhaps very small. And with a wick rotation couldn't this be made into an extra space dimension? Or do all lines in configuration/phase space have to be time-like?

Comment: @lux I meant that only in the mathematical sense that the string is a one-dimensional thing that is mapped point by point into space and then its motion is quantized. I did not suggest that a quantum string is a composite of quantum particles.

Comment: The interpretation is mathematically  wrong - the string is a one dimensional object that traces out a two dimensional worldsheet. There is no sense in thinking of it point by point as a reparameterisation of the worldsheet (or the instantaneous string) would change the labels given to each so called point.